# Why is this VBA code looping indefinitely?

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel table, I have a set of 150,000 lines of numerical data with 31 columns. One column corresponding to 30 variables which were simulated 5000 times. More precisely, the first 30 lines correspond to the first simulation, and so forth.
I want to compute the median of each variable, which means 30 * 31 medians to compute. I have written this code:

```
Function median_simulation()
Dim feuille_statistiques As Worksheet, feuil1 As Worksheet
Dim term As Integer

Set feuil1 = Worksheets("Feuil1")
Set feuille_statistiques = Worksheets("Statistiques")


For i = 102 To 131
    For j = 2 To 32

        Dim rng2 As Range
        term = feuille_statistiques.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Set rng2 = feuil1.Range(feuil1.Cells(1 + term, (j + 5)), feuil1.Cells(1 + term, (j + 5)))

        For k = 1 To 4999
            Set rng2 = Union(rng2, feuil1.Cells(30 * k + 1 + term, (j + 5)))
        Next k

        feuille_statistiques.Cells(i, j).Value = WorksheetFunction.median(rng2)

    Next j
Next i

End Function
```

I don't get why, but trying to run this code leads to a never ending computing. However I believe the code is working since it does when I freeze i and j (I tried with j = 2 and i = 102) Is this some memory issue ? Is my code non optimal and is there a way to improve it ?

Comment: This won't cause an infinite loop but you shouldn't be dimming rng2 over and over inside the loop. Declare it once outside the loop and set it repeatedly inside the loop.

Comment: @Jeeped thanks I am going to try that.

Comment: `median` will work of an array, so use an array rather than the actual range objects.`Dim a() As Variant: a = Array(1, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 500, 7000): Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Median(a)`

Comment: My suggestion is that you do `i=102 to 103` `j=2 to 3` and `k=1 to 2` to see if it's just a very inefficient computation... or simply run it for a bit and hold escape to pause the debugger

Comment: After `For k = 1 To 4999` insert `Debug.Print "i=" & i & ", j=" & j & ", k=" & k` and see the progress.

Comment: Debug.Print won't work because Excel doesn't answer anymore when I run the code. I am going to try with your idea @Nathan_Sav

Comment: `Union()` is not a very cheap operation, and you call it 30 * 30 * 5000 = 4.5M times. This is going to take a while.

Comment: Nathan_Sav and @Andre you were right, I managed to run the code using an array instead of Range and Union. I don't know which one would like to post an answer but I would definitely select one yours. thank you

Comment: Can you not do this in a formula? Then use autofill, or an array, otherwise, you will be waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`median` will work of an array, so use an array rather than the actual range objects.

```
Dim a() As Variant
a = Array(1, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 500, 7000)
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Median(a)
```

For example